# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at Geolib.isDecimal

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a push notification system using Firebase cloud functions, and recently I noticed that the push notifications weren't coming in anymore(they had been working for the past few months). When I go into the logs I'm seeing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at Geolib.isDecimal   (/user_code/node_modules/geolib/dist/geolib.js:1326:26)
at Geolib.useDecimal (/user_code/node_modules/geolib/dist/geolib.js:1241:22)
at Geolib.coords (/user_code/node_modules/geolib/dist/geolib.js:179:85)
at Geolib.getDistance (/user_code/node_modules/geolib/dist/geolib.js:247:26)
at userValue (/user_code/index.js:104:34)
at /user_code/index.js:94:4
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:114:356
at Xb.h.ha (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:50:275)
at Xb.h.ha (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:50:268)
at Xb.h.ha (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:50:310)
```

I haven't changed any of the code, and re-downloaded Geolib but still won't budge, any help would be greatly appreciated.

MY CODE:

```
 exports.postMade = functions.database.ref('/PostData/post/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {

console.log('Someone made a post');

var valueObject = event.data.val();

console.log('the data in valueObject'+ valueObject)

return admin.database().ref('Users').once('value').then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(function(child){
        var values = child.val();
        console.log('the values inside of value'+ values)
         userValue(values.userLat,values.userLong,values.radiusDistance,values.token,valueObject.lat,valueObject.long,valueObject.userUid,valueObject.text)
    })
});
});


function userValue(lat,long,radiusDistance,token,postLat,postLong,postUser,postText){

var unconvertedDistance = geolib.getDistance({latitude: lat, longitude: long}, {latitude: postLat, longitude: postLong});

var convertedDistance = geolib.convertUnit('mi',unconvertedDistance, 0)

console.log('the values of both unconvertedDistance and convertedDistance'+ unconvertedDistance,+ convertedDistance)

if (convertedDistance <= radiusDistance){
const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "Someone posted near you!",
            body: postText,
            badge: "1",
            sound: "default"
        },
    };
const options = {
     priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options);
};
};
```

Comment: One of the parameters being passed in to getDistance is not what you expect.  Make your userValue function console.log lat, long, postLat, postLong and see what you have.  My guess is that one of those things is undefined.

Comment: @James just ran it with the console.log and every value turned up good =/

Comment: Interesting.  A [quick test](https://jsfiddle.net/6n4jyctz/) using pretty boring lat/long values works ok for me.  I wonder if the bug is tied to the browser version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's known [issue](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib/issues/88) on this geoLib package ,Its pending since July 2016

Answer (score 0):

Make sure latitude , longitude and radius are **String**. I had the same problem , i discovered it worked fine with string parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
class Distance {
  toRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  calc(from, to) {
   const lat1 = parseFloat(from.lat);
   const lon1 = parseFloat(from.lng);
   const lat2 = parseFloat(to.lat);
   const lon2 = parseFloat(to.lng);
   const R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
   const dLat = this.deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
   const dLon = this.deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
   const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
   Math.cos(this.deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(this.deg2rad(lat2)) *
   Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
   const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
   const d = R * c; // Distance in km
   return d;
 }

 deg2rad(deg) {
   return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
 }
 }

export default new Distance();
```